# C# - Get version of Setup project msi/exe file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-setup-proje

I'm trying to get the version from MSI/exe files.

Pic

[image]

I tried both exe and msi file but it returns as null.

```
var versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(@"path\setup.exe");
            string version = versionInfo.FileVersion;
```

I tried write the version in the description field and read it but again, it returns as null.

How can I get this field by code ?

Comment: FileVersionInfo can only work on executable files that have a VERSIONINFO resource.  For .msi files you need to use the MSI api.  Project > Add Reference > Browse, select c:\windows\system32\msi.dll to start using the COM component.  I think a version number is available from Document.SummaryInfo, "ProductVersion" property.

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio, right click your project and go to Properties.
From Properties go to Package->General and scroll down to find "File Version".
Here you can set the File Version property of the file when it is compiled.

[image: File Version]

The code you provided can now retrieve the version!

[image: Print File Version]

Comment: Seems OP has already tried this, since it's the same code in question.

Comment: OP set a property called "Version", In my answer I clearly state it's suppose to be the "File Version" for the method he is using.